# Invalid file error, converting image to base64

Tags: python, django

How do I get a image from a image input and convert it into base64.

erorr:  `invalid file: <InMemoryUploadedFile: image.jpg (image/jpeg)>`

```
def fileView(request):

    form = FileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid:
            image = request.FILES.get('image')

            with open(image , "wb") as img:
                img.write(base64.decodebytes(image))

            request.session['image_file'] = img

            return redirect('')
```

Comment: `request.session['image_file'] = base64.decodebytes(request.FILES.get('image').read())`

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, i get a TypeError : 'the image data' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Note you are missing the parentheses in `if form.is_valid():`

Comment: it may be the note of @Alasdair. If that does not work please show the complete error stack.

Comment: actually, you should call `encodebytes`, not `decodebytes`. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)